# Can't install IPA with AdHoc distribution certificate

Tags: ios

Here is the senario where i am facing problem...

I have an App on `Appstore` i have removed it from `appstore` as a result all of my `provisioning certificate` and certificate gone invalid and just now i made then active again ,and while installing those application`,I am using the same provisioning certificate its active now but i am not able to install the app on my device any idea why? Is there something i am doing wrong i am new to IOS.`

Comment: Any idea why down voted am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add your device UDID to the your account.
Or confirm that your device is added to ADHoc certificate.